# The TCP/IP Stack: Simple protocols and IP

Tags: networking

Host 192.168.0.74 wants to talk to host 192.168.0.45 on the same subnet. They have never communicated
before. They will talk IP to one another. However, some message must be transmitted first
before they can communicate. What message is it?”

Comment: IP as in TCP/IP? Or IP as in IP? Tell your teacher/professor to be less obfuscated with their questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's an ARP message as they need to find the network layer address of the respective target network node.